# connman and changing ip addresses back and forth with dhcp

Tags: networking, ip-address, connman

The rules for setting up an IP address on your computer in Linux has changed and now there is this connman thing.  I'm on a Beaglebone black:

```
Linux beaglebone 4.19.94-ti-rt-r72 #1buster SMP PREEMPT RT Tue Mar 8 23:22:50 UTC 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I see there is a file,

```
cat /var/lib/connman/default.config 
[service_eth0]
Type = ethernet
IPv4 = 192.168.1.132/24
```

1. Do I change this file to change my IP address?   For example, if I want my IP address to be 192.168.42.42, do  I just change it in that IPv4 line?
2. If I want to change this to be assigned by the router (dhcp?), what do I do?
3. When does the change take effect? Do I have to reboot and/or stop and restart some service?

Comment: "The rules have changed again": no, there's been several ways to administrate your network interfaces (all of which have been around for > 10 years), and you just chose a Linux distribution that preferred connman over one of the alternatives. Which is fine, and it's also fine to be unaccustomed to that!

Comment: @marcus. yes of course you are correct, to a point however, the "new" way is incompatible to the "old" way, and no direction on making the changeover is available that I can find.  I responsible way to have done this would of been to leave the old "interfaces.config" file, and put in it the directions on how to convert to the new paradigm. As it is, I  am still left with a situation where I can no longer set up my web server. Do you have any answer to my questions?

Comment: I'm typing one as we speak :)

Comment: "I'm typing...."  TY!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: `connmanctl services` to find the card you want to modify, `connmanctl config <service> --ipv4 manual <IP address> <netmask> <gateway>` to set a static IP address, `connmanctl config <service> --ipv4 dhcp` to instead use DHCP.

> The rules for setting up an IP address on your computer in Linux has changed and now there is this connman thing. I'm on a Beaglebone black:

Luckily, not really: connman has been around for 13 years, and it's been very popular in the embedded world, where you simply often wish for a slimmer, if harder to use for a graphical user, system administration, compared to desktop/laptop systems, where most linux distros adopted NetworkManager (due to the old static /etc/network / ifupdown infrastructure just fell flat, because it's very complicated to support things like "plugging in a docking station with a network port", or "enabling wifi with a switch on the side of a laptop"; a use case Linux in its earlier days simply did not see; network cards where integrated ISA or PCI cards in PCs under people's desk, not laptops. So, things got a bit more complicated, because well, the real world is kind of messy :) But that's why there's communities like this one!)

So, this isn't new – it's just different to what you're used to by desktop-style Linux systems. Sorry! Different use cases call for different tooling :)

You can change `connman` configuration files yourself, but I don't think you should; it's probably easier to remember one command that does it for you (and correctly), and which comes with a `help` function. I memorize very little these days – I just get better at reading the right help messages.

In your case, that command is called `connmanctl` (the `ctl` is a contraction for "controller", I think). And it has subcommand, one of which is called `config` and handles the configuration. (Other subcommands include `connman disable`, e.g. to disable wifi should you have that, `connman disable wifi`, for example.

`connmanctl services` will list the ethernet cards you have. You're probably looking for something like `ethernet_MACADDRESSINHEX_cable`; let's call it `$SERVICE` henceforth. Armed with that knowledge:

> Do I change this file to change my IP address? For example, if I want my IP address to be 192.168.42.42, do I just change it in that IPv4 line?

```
connmanctl config $SERVICE --ipv4 manual ${IP_address} ${netmask} ${gateway}
```

where `${netmask}` and `${gateway}` would be the two other things you'd need to determine to set up your interface

> If I want to change this to be assigned by the router (dhcp?), what do I do?

```
connmanctl config $SERVICE --ipv4 dhcp
```

> When does the change take effect? Do I have to reboot and/or stop and restart some service?

`connmanctl connect $SERVICE`

Comment: Thank you for the very complete answer.  My problem is I switch networks all the time, and while the connmanctl might make it easy, it really doesn't document the changes.  For over 13 years, as I change, the IP address I edit the config file by commenting out one line, leave myself a note about what system it WAS attached to and put in a new IP address and WHY I am changing it.   This makes it very convenient when I re-visit clients and can just reset my config files and I'm back on their system.  I would still prefer to manually edit files. Can I do that?

Comment: You can! But even for NetworkManager, what you're doing is quite work-intense, manually commenting out things. What you do is a standard use case! In both a modern desktop Linux and a connman-based embedded linux network stack, you just define services (in NetworkManager lingo, connections) and activate these as desired. No need to comment/uncomment – just tell your startup system which one you want by enabling exactly that service.

Comment: "No need to comment/uncomment"  Your missing the point, I LIKE the comment and uncomment.  "$ find / -iname "*.conf"|xargs grep -Hin "jleslie48" and I get a list of every config file that I have edited anywhere in the system. Now I don't have to have a different rule for connman, NetworkManager, git, source code, bash-scripts, txt files, whatever.  It all just shows up and for 30 years all I have to do is drop in a comment with the word "jleslie48" in it.  I don't want the "wizard", just tell me the name of the files I have to edit.

Comment: you can still do that :) nothing stops you from having that name in the config files, and next to the line which selects which of the connections to bring up :)

Comment: thanks!   I know I can still do this, but I need to know what connmanctl commands actually do/modify to add my comments!   that's my original question, can I just modify that file from the original question or are there other files that need to be editted?